# Does "C&#43;&#43;" instead of "C++" hinder search engine indexing?

Tags: html, search-engine, html-entities, asciidoctor

I have a web page with "C++" in its title generated by `asciidoctor`. In the source, I use `{cpp}` character-replacement attribute, but in the resulting HTML file, asciidoctor renders it into `C&#43;&#43;` instead of plain `C++`. I just wonder about web search engine indexing, whether there is any difference between those two variants. (For instance, Google HTML Style Guide recommends [avoiding HTML entities](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#Entity_References)). Or, if there is possibly any option to force asciidoctor to produce `C++`?

Answer (score 2):

The built-in `{cpp}` attribute uses HTML entities to represent the plus signs because it might get used in a URL. If you are certain that your use does not involve URLs, you can simply redefine the attribute:

```
:cpp: C++
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's safe to assume that search engines are smart enough to decode HTML entities before indexing.

The reason the style guide says to avoid them is most likely for readability. Google's JS style guide has a [similar recommendation](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#non-ascii-characters):

> ```js
> /* Best: perfectly clear even without a comment. */
> const units = 'μs';
>
> /* Allowed: but unncessary as μ is a printable character. */
> const units = '\u03bcs'; // 'μs'
>
> /* Poor: the reader has no idea what character this is. */
> const units = '\u03bcs';
> ```